# How to consume a Restful Service or any data layer using Orchard CMS

Tags: rest, content-management-system, orchardcms

Since I started working on an Orchard CMS and playing and creating a website that I can build, maybe one of the guys out there would like to share an Idea how can I consume data from a Restful service, or any data layer. The requirements that I'm looking into is, First, I need to create a GridView UI, where I can show data or list and Second, Need to have a form where a user can have a CRUD functionality.